# How to get last post for multiple facebook pages (one for each)?

Tags: php, facebook, stream, facebook-fql

Is there any way to get ONLY the latest post from stream for each page you like?

```
fql?q=
{
    "pg":"SELECT page_id FROM page_fan where uid = me() LIMIT 5",
    "post":"SELECT message, actor_id, source_id, created_time FROM stream 
            WHERE source_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #pg) 
            ORDER BY created_time desc LIMIT 5"
}
```

Here, you query 5 page from your liked pages but my goal is to get ONLY the latest post from each of the 5 page ordered by created time (desc). This query works but it's return more posts for one page than only the latest for me, and I cant figure out how to get only the latest post for one page..

***UPDATE:***

I would like it to give back the latest post for EACH of the 5 page. like:

page1 - latest post of page 1; page2 - latest post of page 2; page3 - latest post of page 3; and so on in a created time order (desc.)...

**Currently my script does this:**

page1 - latest post of page1; page2 - latest post of page 2; page2 - 2nd latest post of page 2; page2 - 3rd latest post of page 2; page4 - latest post of page 4; ... absolutely random :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited post**

Indeed, your FQL query just grabs the 5 most recent posts from 5 of the pages you like. I don't see any way to get the first post of each page in only one query. You will have to:

1. Get the ID of the pages you like: `SELECT page_id FROM page_fan where uid = me() LIMIT 5`,
2. Loop on each `page_id` (using PHP),
3. Get the first post of the page: `SELECT message, actor_id, source_id, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id='page_id' LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, that is not my problem :)
if you set it to 1 then its just give only one post for all 5 page..
I would like it to give back the latest post for EACH of the 5 page.
like:
page1 -  latest post of page 1;
page2 -  latest post of page 2;
page3 -  latest post of page 3;
and so on... Currently my script does this: page1 - latest post of page1;
page2 - latest post of page 2;
page2 - 2nd latest post of page 2;
page2 - 3rd latest post of page 2;
page4 - latest post of page 4;
... absolutely random :(

Comment: You are right! I edited my post to give you a way to do that, which you probably already implemented.

Comment: Thank You very much! Well Im not a php user (always used FQL) but it seems there is no other way to do that, only with php.. :)